# Upload realm file from realm server to AWS S3 bucket in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, realm

I'm not asking about uploading a file from a browser to a nodejs script.

But I am looking for the option to upload the file to another server, example I will have a nodejs in server called A,

I want to upload the file(/file_path/filename.realm) to Server called B(AWS S3).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use aws-sdk for this purpose and you follow:

(Note: Considering that you have access to AWS S3 and already created it)

1. initiate a new instance of S3.
2. read content from a file (realm file) with the fs module.
3. Assign the contents of the realm file to Body of upload params.
4. call the upload function.

sample code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
accessKeyId: <awsS3AccessId>, // access Id of your bucket
secretAccessKey:<awsS3SecretKey>, // secret key of your bucket
 });

const uploadFile = (fileName) => {
    // Read content from the file
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName);

    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: fileName, // File name you want to save as in S3
        Body: fileContent
    };

    // Uploading files to the bucket
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
    });
};
```